# Bootstrap Modal Overflowing. How to correct it? (Centering)

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

```
  <div class="row">
    <br/><br/><br/>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact" data-original-title>
          Adopt
        </a>
        <div class="modal fade" id="contact" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contactLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
```

[image: Bootstrap Overflow]

As shown in the image, my modal over extends. I can only show the head parts of the code. What did i do wrong? My other modals are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by modifying the CSS of modal-dialog.